# What is the 'admin_action_' . $_REQUEST['action'] hook used for?

Tags: plugins, hooks, actions

There's an action hook triggered in `admin.php` called `'admin_action_'.$_REQUEST['action']`. Unfortunately, it's a bit useless for plugins as it's triggered at the very end of admin.php, after everything's loaded on the page (even the footer).

Does anyone know why it's there, why in that silly position and if anything is using it internally?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Via the "Annotate" function the the Trac, [you can see that this was added three years ago](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-admin/admin.php?annotate=blame&rev=17333#L235), after the request for [a generic POST handler that plugins can use](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/7283).

Google code search tells me that [at least Akismet uses this hook](http://google.com/codesearch?hl=en&lr=&q=admin_action+package%3asvn.wp-plugins.org&sbtn=Search), and [it appeared there at the time it was introduced in core](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/61062/akismet/trunk/akismet.php). It works [by calling `admin.php` directly](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/akismet/tags/2.5.3/admin.php#L475) (and not the plugin page). From there [it can just do a redirect at the end](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/akismet/tags/2.5.3/admin.php#L692). The trick is thus to call `admin.php?action=your_action`, other URLs are not guaranteed to work.

Many (but not all) admin pages include `admin.php`, as a sort of initialization. In this case your action would be fired before any output is sent, because the admin page includes `admin-header.php` after `admin.php`. This won't work on every admin page: not all of them include `admin.php`, and others have checks for "rogue" `action` query variables, and give you a *"Are you sure you want to do that?"* warning ([due to missing nonces?](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-includes/functions.php#L2545)). [For a plugin page `admin.php` does everything](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-admin/admin.php#L144): it displays the header ([unless the `noheader` query variable is in the URL](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-admin/admin.php#L148)), calls your page, and displays the footer (unless you called `exit()` in your code!). `admin.php` then calls `exit()` itself, so the `admin_action_` hook is not even called there.

Comment: @Jan Fabry: You're a bit mistaken there (i studied admin.php up and down). It includes everything (admin-header.php, the pages themselves, and admin-footer.php) within that single file. And after it's done all that comes that call. So it is the last thing executed. Thanks for the pointers, though, i'll have a look.

Comment: @wyrfel: I know, I just finished a major edit of my answer. It now includes how Akismet does it. The trick is to not use your plugin page as the form action handler. When you are on a plugin page, [`admin.php` even calls `exit` before this action is reached](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-admin/admin.php#L173), so it is not called at all.

Comment: @Jan Fabry: The `noheader` qv is a good hint, too. Thanks for digging that up.

Comment: @wyrfel: OK, the fact that `admin.php` gets included in many (but not all) admin pages put me on the wrong track. This hook only works when you call `admin.php` directly. I have updated this answer, and now I know enough to answer [your related question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10500/how-do-i-best-handle-custom-plugin-page-actions)!

Comment: @Jan Fabry: Lol...i think that should be flagged as a duplicate, now. ;-) Thanks for all that.

Comment: @wyrfel: No, the other question is good when you are developing a plugin. This question is good when you are reading the WP code. It's not guaranteed that people will find this question when they are looking for the other one. And maybe there are other good ways to handle plugin actions besides this one?

Comment: @Jan Fabry: Ahh you just want to get the reputation for both. ;-) Naa, you're right, of course. Just because i asked both out of the same motivation doesn't mean they are really duplicates.