# List Table action argument not cleared

Tags: plugin-development

I use a subclass of the list table class in my plugin to list logged mails. You can select multiple mails to resend or delete. The form data is send to the same page again.

The entries are sortable. This means for the header columns links are created by appending the orderby and order GET-parameters (base class behavior) to the current url.

Select a mail and action resend.
Before actions:

```
admin.php?page=wpml_plugin_log
```

Submit

After page submitted and actions handled:

```
admin.php?page=wpml_plugin_log&bulkactionsnonce=3bb20a74fd&_wp_http_referer=%2Fwp-admin%2Fadmin.php%3Fpage%3Dwpml_plugin_log&search_date&s&_wpnonce=35ec405ae8&action=resend&email%5B0%5D=59&action2=-1&orderby=timestamp&order=asc
```

But I expect no 'action', 'action1', 'email' arguments in the url anymore.

The link after the actions are processed contains the 'action' param. This means if you change the order of the columns the mail is resend over and over again (this makes no sense). The url also grows and results in a URI too long webserver-error (in case of apache) after some time of usage. 
How can I avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Let me start with a question: What if the user simply refreshes the page after the action is processed? It will resubmit the action.

So the issue is not only with the links for the sortable column header and how WP_List_Table is generating them but with the way you are handling the action requests.

The best practice is to redirect the user back to a URL excluding the action parameter after processing the action, and have the page rendered on the second request instead of rendering it on the action request.

For example:

1. User starts here: `admin.php?page=wpml_plugin_log`
2. User sends a request to `admin.php?page=wpml_plugin_log&action=delete&id=123`
3. Delete action is handled
4. User is redirected back to `admin.php?page=wpml_plugin_log&delete_success=123`

As you see above, you may also add some other parameters (`delete_success`) to the redirect URL to pass the state of the handled action to the second request.

Comment: The redirect is what I came up with too (appeding only order, orderby, paged, s etc but not the actions). I did not find a appropriate location to do this redirect. If i try a redirect in the process_bulk_actions I get the error that the headers already sent. Do you know a plugin that implements this so I can look at the code?

Comment: @No3x You can handle it in `load-{$page_hook}` action which fires before including the `admin-header.php`.

Comment: I can't redirect there because then no action is exectued.

Comment: Why not? I guess you are calling your `process_bulk_actions()` in your list class' `prepare_items()` method, right? That is not necessarily the appropriate place to handle the actions. Call your `process_bulk_actions()` in `load-{$page_hook}` action hook instead. @No3x

Comment: Also see here for another solution using the `admin_action_{$action}` hook: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10500/how-do-i-best-handle-custom-plugin-page-actions

Comment: Yes I called `process_bulk_actions` in `prepare_items`. I tested the `load-{$page_hook}` approach but headers are already sent at this point too. `PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at wp-includes/class.wp-styles.php:237) in wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1210`

Comment: The `admin_action_{$action}` doesn't seem to work because the `action` field is already used by the list table. 
`add_action( 'admin_action_resend', array($this, 'process_bulk_action'));` and 
`add_action( 'admin_action_myAddedFieldValue', array($this, 'process_bulk_action'));` do not get fired.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67243/discussion-between-parham-and-no3x).